# Как решить проблему с зависанием экрана в ноутбуке

Tags: nvidia

Хочу поделиться с своей проблемой, которая меня уже достала не один год. У меня ноутбук Toshiba Satellite A665-S6094. Дело в том, что частенько зависает экран при просмотре видео в полный экран и не только, просто зависает и всё. Раньше стоял Windows 7, потом перешёл на   Windows 10, когда начались обновления и началась проблема. Связывался с производителями видео карты NVIDIA, выполнял все их рекомендации и всё впустую. Перешёл назад на Windows 7, история повторилась. Потом перешёл на Linux, какое то время было спокойно,НО  потом всё повторилось. Все рекомендации по поводу комбинаций всяких клавиш не работают, просто тупо выключаю ноутбук и опять включаю. Вот данные ноутбука:

Toshiba Satellite A665-S6094

Процессор
Intel (R) Core (TM) i7 CPU Q 740 @ 1,73 ГГц

Плата
Название
NWQAA
Производитель
TOSHIBA (TOSHIBA, [www.toshiba.com](http://www.toshiba.com))
Версия
1,00

BIOS
Дата
24.11.11
Производитель
TOSHIBA (TOSHIBA, [www.toshiba.com](http://www.toshiba.com))
Версия
2.30

Дисплей
Разрешение
1366x768 пикселей
Рендер OpenGL
GeForce 310M / PCIe / SSE2
Поставщик X11
Фонд X.Org

Аудио устройства
Звуковая карта
HDA-Intel - HDA Intel MID
Звуковая карта
HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia

Память
8081 Мб

SCSI диски
ATA CT480BX500SSD1

Optiarc DVD RW AD-7703S

Операционная система
Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia

OpenGL
Производитель
Корпорация NVIDIA
Рендер
GeForce 310M / PCIe / SSE2
Версия
3.3.0 NVIDIA 340.108
Графическое ускорение
Да

Wi-fi модуль: Intel Centrino Advanced-N + WiMax 6250
Model: 622ANXHMW
Если кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой и решил её, прошу поделиться.
С наилучшими пожеланиями,
Владимир.

Comment: Ноут греется сильно? Видюшка довольно старая - 10 лет Дрова для карты обновляли?

Comment: Нет, не греется, к тому же я поменял недавно термопасту. Дрова для карты не обновлял, но когда приходят обновления, то всё обновляется. Остальное работает отлично.

Comment: Попробуйте обновить драйвера видеокарты https://www.nvidia.ru/download/driverresults.aspx/77315/ru

Comment: Этот драйвер для 32 битной системы

Comment: Тогда попробуйте вот эту ссылку https://www.nvidia.ru/Download/index.aspx?lang=ru

Comment: Пробовал, не проходит под Linux 64-bit, потом попробовал под Windows 10,11, тоже не проходит. Не знаю, как картинку вложить, но то, что у меня стоит:

Comment: NVIDIA-340(рекомендованный) Версия 340.108-0ubuntu0.18.04.1. Есть ещё вариант(тоже его пробовал) xserver-xorg-video-nouveau(свободный) Версия 1:1.0.15-2 X.Org X server-Nouveau driver. Есть ещё один вариант, но его не пробовал: NVIDIA-304 Версия 304.137-0ubuntu2 NVIDIA legacy binary driver version 304.137

Comment: Связался с специалистами из NVIDIA  и мне сказали, что последний драйвер для моей карты 342.01 Может кто-нибудь подскажет где его конкретно скачать? На этом сайте его нет

Comment: Я рекомендую ставить не последнюю версию драйвера, а доступную для вашей ОС https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-on-linux-mint

Comment: Вот что выдало по Вашей ссылке:$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000A70sv00001179sd0000FD30bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GT218M [GeForce 310M]
driver   : nvidia-304 - third-party non-free
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
И как Вы видите, рекомендуется nvidia-340, а у меня установлена Версия 340.108-0ubuntu0.18.04.1. Так что дело видно не совсем в карте, а скорее всего в её настройке.